# Error in acl-sequelize as concecuence of upgrade version in sequelize from v5 to v6

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js

**Error:** the console show that ... }).nodeify(cb); from backend.js is not a function.

```
Node version: v18.14.2 also tested with v16.14.2
Sequelize version: 6.31.1 (latest at this moment)
acl-sequelize version: 0.3.5 (latest at this moment)
```

I'm trying to migrate sequelize from v5 to v6, one big change is Sequelize.Promise is no longer available in v6,
This is likely due to a breaking change in Sequelize version 6, where they removed the Promise property in favor of using the global Promise object. This means that any code that relies on Sequelize.Promise will no longer work in version 6 or later.
I saw that acl-sequelize still using sequelize v5 [specifically 5.9.4], I think this is the problem here,
Can someone give me please some recomendation about my error please.
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

This fork work for me.
https://github.com/sthumma/node_acl_sequelize
You can use it in your package.json like this:

`"acl-sequelize": "git+https://github.com/sthumma/node_acl_sequelize"`
I hope it helps.